# How to directly go to App Store with Firebase dynamic link in iOS?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Using Firebase dynamic link in the iOS App. It's working when app is installed, but if the app is not installed it going to the App Store but showing a another page before going to the App Store.
Please check below image.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those are app preview pages: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews#app_preview_pages

These allow for deep linking after install, and avoid some issues with jumping straight to the app store. You can customise them by providing metadata in your link, or disable them by using the parameter `efr=1`.

Comment: If I set forcedRedirectEnabled = true (efr=1) it always redirects to the app store even though app is installed. If I set it to false it's working fine.

Comment: Maybe file an issue with support about that: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , i found it was because i didn't add the app store id you should add IOS parameters in this format

```
.setIosParameters(
            new DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder("com.example.ios")
                    .setAppStoreId("123456789")
                    .setMinimumVersion("1.0.1")
                    .build())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. It was because I had wrong app Id in the Firebase project settings. Open button started work correctly when I set correct App store Id.